# Rails & MySQL - Saved HTML Being Truncated at HTML Entity

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm saving whole HTML documents in the database with ActiveRecord. I can see in the logs that correct INSERT statements are being generated and sent to MySQL but when I actually look in the database after the save has completed, the content is truncated.

It appears that `&nbsp;` entities in the document are causing this truncation. I can URL encode the document or something to avoid this happening but I'd much rather understand *why* this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an encoding issue - make sure your read the HTML in as UTF8.